# Can a friend class invoke a private constructor in c++? (and what's Singleton)

Tags: c++, private-constructor, friend-class

Consider class A and B. Class A is befriended by class B. Class B has a private constructor. Can class A create class B instances, or is a private constructor an indication to the compiler that the class *cannot* be instantiated, even by a friend class?
Here's some sample code:

```
class B;

class A {
    void myFunction() {
        B newBobject;
    }
};

class B {
    private:
        B() {}
    public:
        int someData;
        friend class A;
};
```

Also, note I'm using C++03. If it's not valid in C++03, is it allowed in C++11?

As a side question, how is the Singleton method related? Does it deal specifically with instantiating one and only one instance of an object, or is it something else?

Comment: Do you mean Sin*g*leton?

Comment: @OliCharlesworth Did that compile I would consider a very poor judge in these cases...

Comment: Whoops! sry yes 'Singleton'

Comment: @paul23: It's in no way definitive, but it would have been a start... ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code(more like your idea) is actually error free and valid on both [C++03](http://liveworkspace.org/code/4em8S3%244) and [c++11](http://liveworkspace.org/code/4em8S3%243).

There are 2 errors in your code however. To create an object of type B, you need to see the entire definition of B, and that means the definitions of B and A need to be exchanged.

Secondly, you need to make `myfunction` public, or call it from within class A.

To answer your other question.. Most singletons are implemented somewhat like this..

```
class Singleton{
private:

   Singleton(){}
public:
   static Singleton& GetInstance(){
       static Singleton instance;
       return instance;
   }
};
```

This would prevent anybody but the Singleton class (and a friend as you have discovered) from making an instance of the class, so it is easier to enforce the 1 object rule. The Singleton will be accessed as `Singleton::GetInstance()`.

This and other possible implementations are shown at [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern#Example).

Comment: thx! But would I _have_ to make myFunction public? I could add a call to it in some public function in A - but I guess that doesn't matter.

Comment: @AUTO yup, you dont HAVE to make it public, i had to, to call it from main.

Comment: For your Singleton example, is it required or optional to put: `Singleton& GetInstance() const`?

Comment: @AUTO Ah!! I missed it, the function has to be static, so const doesnt make sense.